# Mysql update one column or multiple columns with one update statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Is it possible to update either one or several columns in a table using the same SQL statement?

For example I may want to occasionally update a users email or their weight. Maybe at the same time and maybe at different times.

I would ideally like one function to update user. Is there a way to achieve this or am I going to have to write SQL update statements for each scenario?

Comment: The easiest way I can think is create a stored procedure.

Comment: You can provide a list of columns to an update statement. You don't need to do more than one statement.

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server? Also, are you just asking how to do something like this: `UPDATE my_table SET column_x = 'foo', column_y = 'bar' WHERE id = 5;`

Comment: Removed the conflicting product tagd. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: "items" is such a vague term in this context. Your question suggests you want to update multiple fields as opposed to multiple records.I suggest you update the question and the title accordingly.

Comment: I've updated as per your suggestions.  thx.

Comment: DavidG, I'm asking to do that statement in your comment in the case where column_x has a new value and column_y has a new value which will work fine.  But I also want to use the statement where column_x has a new value but column_y has the same value and does not need to be updated.  Obviously I can write a new statement for that case but for simplicity I want to see if just not defining the item in another column will leave that field untouched.